# Use jQuery Deferred inside plugin to always call cleanup method

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm writing a jQuery UI plugin. Inside that plugin, when an action occurs, I'm invoking one of the plugin options as a callback. Once that callback is completed, I want to run some cleanup code.

To be more specific, my plugin uses jQuery UI draggable and droppable. On droppable **drop**, I invoke a function defined in the options called **update**. After **update** is called, which is an AJAX call, I want to perform some cleanup. I don't want the user of the plugin to be required to perform this cleanup call; I want the cleanup call to happen automatically after the update AJAX method is successful.

I thought using jQuery's Deferred made sense here. Here's some code for the plugin's **drop** implementation:

```
self.connectedLists = $(self.options.connectWith)
    .not(self.list)
    .droppable({
        hoverClass: 'ui-selectablelist-active',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var sender = $(ui.draggable).closest('ul'),
                deferred = self.options.update.call(self, e, {
                    sender: sender,
                    receiver: $(this),
                    items: selectedItems
                });

            deferred.then(function () {
                self.removeSelectedItems();
            });
        }
    });
```

And the code for the plugin implementer looks like this:

```
update: function (e, ui) {
    var self = this;
    return $.post(url, 
            {                 
                // some data                         
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log('updated!');
            });
}
```

I'm returning the AJAX call as a promise to the **drop** callback. Inside the drop callback, I want to perform the cleanup operation **removeSelectedItems** always, so I use the .then() function. It doesn't seem to be running.

Does this pattern sound like a good idea. Can anyone help me with this design? Why isn't my done function running inside the **drop** callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.then`, use `.always`.

`.then` is used for adding callbacks to a deferred object:

```
deferred.then(donecallbacks,failcallbacks)
```

Try:

```
self.connectedLists = $(self.options.connectWith)
    .not(self.list)
    .droppable({
        hoverClass: 'ui-selectablelist-active',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var sender = $(ui.draggable).closest('ul'),
                deferred = self.options.update.call(self, e, {
                    sender: sender,
                    receiver: $(this),
                    items: selectedItems
                });

            deferred.always(function () {
                self.removeSelectedItems();
            });
        }
    });
```

**Update:**

Since the developer will be specifying the update function, there's always a possibility of the developer not properly returning the deferred object to you. You should check for that and throw an exceiption in that case.

```
self.connectedLists = $(self.options.connectWith)
    .not(self.list)
    .droppable({
        hoverClass: 'ui-selectablelist-active',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var sender = $(ui.draggable).closest('ul'),
                deferred = self.options.update.call(self, e, {
                    sender: sender,
                    receiver: $(this),
                    items: selectedItems
                });
            if (deferred.always) {
                deferred.always(function () {
                  self.removeSelectedItems();
                });
            }
            else {
                $.error("Update must return a deferred object.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ya. I added if (!deferred) throw 'The update option method must return a Promise object'; after my first post. Great minds...

Comment: The then call actually worked, but I agree it's more appropriate to use always.